# Using Watir WebDriver on headless Centos 6.4 (64 bit)

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

I have setup Watir environment using puppet with modules applied for:

1. epel
2. gems , package { ['watir-webdriver', 'headless', 'bacon', 'selenium-webdriver']:
3. phantomJS
4. rvm (rvm use ruby-2.1.1)
5. xvfb
6. Firefox

now, if i run basic test:

```
basic_headless.rb 
    require 'watir-webdriver'
    require 'headless'
        headless = Headless.new
        headless.start
    b = Watir::Browser.start 'www.google.com'
    puts b.title
    b.close
headless.destroy
```

prints "Google"

and the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'headless'
require 'bacon'
apache_auth   = 'https://l_backup:ke0' + vm_name + '/cgi-bin/administrator/customer.cgi'
user_login    = 'sales_test'
user_password = 'sst'
puts "Logging into " + vm_name + " with " + user_password

Bacon.extend Bacon.const_get(format) rescue abort "No such formatter: #{format}"
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
browser.window.resize_to(1450, 750)
browser.window.move_to(0, 0)
describe "UI Testing for Coder-Workspace" do

    it "Login" do
      browser.goto apache_auth
      browser.text_field(:id => 'login_input').set user_login
      browser.text_field(:id => 'pw_input').set user_password

      browser.form(:name => 'loginform').submit
      browser.frame(:index => 1).html.should.include 'superuser'

    end
```

Displays error:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.40.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/service.rb:50:in `start': unable to connect to chromedriver http://127.0.0.1:9515 (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.40.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/bridge.rb:15:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.40.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:37:in `new'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.40.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:37:in `for'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.40.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:67:in `for'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.8/lib/watir-webdriver/browser.rb:46:in `initialize'
    from code_lookup.rb:34:in `new'
    from code_lookup.rb:34:in `<main>'
```

Now, should i connect to a selenium server ? or a watir Grid ? as proxy to run the tests ? 
Why is it trying to connect to `chromedriver http://127.0.0.1:9515`
I have installed chromedriver manually in /usr/bin, and chmod 777 it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm assuming from the error message that line 34 in `code_lookup.rb` is the line `browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome`. If this is incorrect, this answer is probably as well.)

The reason your first script works is because the default browser in Watir-Webdriver is Firefox:

```
# From line 28 in https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver/blob/master/lib/watir-webdriver/browser.rb
def start(url, browser = :firefox, *args)
```

In the second script, you specific `:chrome`. Easy to solve if your goal is general purpose browsing: remove the `:chrome`

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new # <= same as :firefox
```

The hard part comes if you want to use Chrome specifically. It is not possible to 'correctly' install Chrome and the chromedriver on Centos 6.x, as it is not supported by Google (really). [I've writen about this here](http://themasteroftheinternet.com/blog/2013/11/6/chromedriver-watir-webdriver-on-centos-6-cant-be-done), though I was on a 32-bit system, so hopefully you have more luck than I did.

The best answer I got on my StackOverflow question with the same content (no link -- it was down voted and subsequently auto-deleted) was to install something that has GLIBCXX_3.4.15 as a dependency. I was still unable to get chromedriver to recognize it was installed after doing so.